# How to use pubnub timetoken to handle page refreshes

Tags: javascript, pubnub

When pubnub is connected, users inside my app receive messages no problem. However, let's say they refresh the page or go to another page within the app. There's a 2 -> 5 seconds of downtime before the user can connect to pubnub again. During this time some pubnub messages may be missed.

Thankfully, the [pubnub subscribe API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api-reference-sdk-v4#subscribe) allows you to specify a `timetoken` to point to a past time (e.g. 10 seconds ago).

```
pubnub.subscribe({
  channels: ['my_channel'],
  timetoken: '13534398158620385'
});
```

Description:

*Specifies timetoken from which to start returning any available cached messages.*

**Question:**
What's the safest way to specify this `timetoken` such that few messages are missed?

Comment: 2 - 5 seconds for a page load? I'd consider optimizing your page loads. We haven't had anyone submit a support ticket with this issue. But your answer below is solid. Nice work.

Comment: @CraigConover I wanted to keep the question pretty basic so this is just an example. Note, load here refers to webpage load, as opposed to how long it takes pubnub to load.

Comment: Right, that was my understanding. Just wondering what the content is that takes that long. Perhaps you could hit PubNub first before loading the content?

Comment: Potentially. Either way, there's gonna be a period of downtime though.

Comment: Right, just saying nothing special has had to be implemented for many web apps using PubNub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, listen out for `beforeunload` events on the window. These will be fired before the page is moved away from. Inside this create a cookie to save the current `timetoken`:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  // pubnub timetokens are 17 digits long
  const timetoken = `${now}0000`;

  createCookie(PUBNUB_TIMETOKEN_COOKIE, timetoken, EXPIRATION);
});
```

Note: `PUBNUB_TIMETOKEN_COOKIE` and `EXPIRATION` are constants of your choosing. I set my cookie to expire after 10 seconds to prevent clashes. Also you'll need to define a `createCookie` function similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103596/1627613).

Next, when subscribing to pubnub on page load, use this cookie if it exists:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
  channels: ['my_channel'],
  timetoken: getCookie(PUBNUB_TIMETOKEN_COOKIE)
});
```

This way, if the user refreshes or navigates to another page, missed messages should be caught.